# Maximum or minimum point of a vetor valued function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

We know that a a point of maximum or minimum of a real-valued function can be defined. Is there some notion of maximum or minimum of a vector-valued function? For example, if $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $f(t)=(f_1(t),f_2(t))$ where $f_i:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ are given functions for $i=1,2$.

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that you meant $\Bbb R^2$ instead of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: You can always compose the function with another function $g:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$  and look for maxima of $g\circ f$. For example with $n=2$: $g(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ - an (Euclidean) norm. (At which point does the vector $f(t)$ have the maximum magnitude?)

Answer (score 0):

We talk about maximum and minimum of a real-valued function because there is a natural order in $\Bbb R$. In $\Bbb R^n$, with $n>1$, there is not. The best that you can get (again, when $n>1$) is to aim at the maximum (or minimum) of $\|f\|$ (for some norm, not necessarily the usual one).